Spring AOP не видит метод , просто выводится "You took your book"
Аспект:
package com.aspects;

import org.aspectj.lang.annotation.Aspect;
import org.aspectj.lang.annotation.Before;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;


@Aspect
@Component
public class logging_aspects {
    @Before("execution(public void com.aop.library.getBook())")
    public  void  BeforeGetBookAdvice(){
        System.out.println("Before advice : getBook");
    }

}

Файл конфигурации:
package com.aop;

import org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScan;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.EnableAspectJAutoProxy;

@Configuration
@ComponentScan("com/aop")
@EnableAspectJAutoProxy
public class aop_config {
}

Вот сам метод:
package com.aop;

import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

@Component()
public class library {
    public void getBook(){
        System.out.println("You took your book!");
    }
}


В вашем коде конфигурации aop_config используется путь "com/aop". Правильно использовать "com.aop"
И почитайте книгу "Чистый код" Робина Мартина.

ну это не помогает


Необходимо поместить бин аспекта в контекст:
 public class aop_config {

     @Bean
     public logging_aspects aspect() {
         return new logging_aspects();
     }



@Aspect не является стереотипной аннотацией.
@Component тоже не сработал.

В методе main() нужно вызывать метод бина типа library. Тогда логика аспекта выполнится.
public class Main {
     public static void main(String[] args) {
         AnnotationConfigApplicationContext c = new 
             AnnotationConfigApplicationContext(aop_config.class);

         logging_aspects service = c.getBean(logging_aspects.class);
         System.out.println(service);

         library libr = c.getBean(library.class);
         libr.getBook();
     }}



В методе добавлена проверка присутствия в контексте бина-аспекта.
